# if statement not working for tcsh but works fine on bash

Tags: unix, tcsh

This is working fine on bash but I need to get it working in tcsh. Below is the code I use:

```
if [ -e ~/test/file ]; then echo 'yes'; else echo | mail -s 'not done' abc@gmail.com ; fi
```

This basic code gives me an error saying `if: Expression Syntax`.

I have no idea what the error means and not sure why the if statement is not working. I have spaces before/after brackets. I tried `if ( test -f ~/test/file )` and got the same error.

I am lost as by default I use bash and this error gives no insight. I see a few similar cases but  nothing about checking existence of a file.

Comment: See: http://www.csem.duke.edu/Cluster/csh_basics.htm#if

Comment: I see but is there no way to keep it all in one line. I want this executed as a single line.

Comment: @yatici: The best way to do a one-line `if` in tcsh is `sh -c 'if [ ... ] ; then ... ; else ... ; fi'`, or replace `sh -c` by `bash -c` if you need Bash-specific features.

Answer (score 1):

See the 'File inquiry operators' section of the tcsh man page.

The tcsh sytnax for what you are describing is

```
if ( -e ~/test/file ) then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo | mail -s 'not done' abc@gmail.com
endif
```

Note that tcsh isn't good at running pieces of code on one line.

Comment: so I can't do this in a single line ha?

Comment: I saw a kludgy way to do it one time, search for 'tcsh if one line'. My usual solution to tcsh problems is to run bash ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can run on one line using the test command in a sequence of commands:

```
test -e ~/test/file && echo 'yes' || mail -s 'not done' abc@gmail.com
```

or if you are not interested in the positive case, you can use the short "if" format

```
if ( ! -e ~/test/file ) mail -s 'not done' abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way that I was referring to in my answer.